# set and clear interval by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

I simply want to clear previous interval and set a new one when an ajax call is made.

The current code is:

```
$("#title-form").change(function () {
    var title = $(this).val().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/timing_check/',
        type: "get",
        data: {
        'title': title
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var interval = null;
            if(data.count_down){
            var _second = 1000;
            var _minute = _second * 60;
            var timer;
            var end = data.count_down
            mins = Math.floor(end / 60);
            secs = end % 60;

            var interval = setInterval(count,1000)
            function count(){
               console.log(parseInt(secs)) 
               secs -= 1

            }}
            else{
                var stop = function(){
                clearInterval(interval);}     
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I tryed many recommended variations to be able to clear the interval from outside of the function. Such as;

setting the "interval" variable to null or to false,

window.setInterval,

writing the count function inside of setInterval,

writing the count function as a separate function outside of the ajax function,

But neither of the variations cleared the interval.

Later on I'll also need to clear the interval on keydown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I will do like below (P.S. didn't test):

```
var interval = null,
    secs = 0;
function count() {
    console.log(secs);
    secs -= 1;
}
function deal_data(data) {
    if(interval == null && data.count_down){
        var end = data.count_down
        secs = end % 60;

        interval = setInterval(count, 1000);
    else if (interval != null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}


$("#title-form").change(function () {
    var title = $(this).val().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/timing_check/',
        type: "get",
        data: { 'title': title },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            deal_data(data);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, the code has minor typos but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

After several changes to MarshalSHI's answer the code ended up like this:

```
$("#title-form").change(function () {
    var title = $(this).val().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/timing_check/',
        type: "get",
        data: { 'title': title },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            deal_data(data);
        }
    })
})

var interval = null;

function deal_data(data) {
    if(interval == null && data.count_down){
        var end = data.count_down
        secs = end % 60;

        interval = setInterval(count, 1000);}
    else if (interval != null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}

function count() {
    console.log(secs);
    secs -= 1;
}
```